# Congruence modulo n

Tags: number-theory

I have following two relations in $x_1$ and $x_2$

1. $(\alpha b-\beta a)(x_1-x_2)\equiv 0\pmod{n}$
2. $(\alpha b-\beta a)\{[\frac{x_1-1}{n}]-[\frac{x_2-1}{n}]\}\equiv 0\pmod{n}$, where $[\frac{}{}]$ is greatest integer.

Here, $(\alpha b-\beta a)$ is prime to $n$. How can I prove that $x_1=x_2$?

The article says that relation (2) shows that $x_1$ and $x_2$ lie between the same two multiples of $n$. For since the values of $[(n-1)/n]$ range between $0$ and $n-1$ the congruence $[\frac{x_1-1}{n}]\equiv[\frac{x_2-1}{n}]\pmod{n}$ is an equality. But $x_1$ and $x_2$ lie between the same two multiples of $n$ so we get $x_1=x_2$. I am not able to understand this.

Comment: I don’t think the claim follows, at least from what you give. Say $n=3$, $x_1=22$, and $x_2=13$. More generally, the first equation requires $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod{n}$. The second implies that if we write $x_1= qn+r$, $0\leq r\lt n$, and $x_2 = pn+r$, then $q\equiv p\pmod{n}$. Don’t see how they obtain their claim, unless you happen to know something else about $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion does not seem to follow from the facts you have given so far.

Since $\alpha b - \beta a$ is prime to $n$, the first equation yields that $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod{n}$.

Now, write $x_1= kn + r$ with $0\leq r\lt n$, and $x_2 = qn+r$ (same $r$, since $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod{n}$.

If $r\gt 0$, then $\frac{1}{n}(x_1-1) = k + \frac{r-1}{n}$, and $\frac{1}{n}(x_2-1) = q+\frac{r-1}{n}$, hence the floor of these expressions are $k$ and $q$. If $r=0$, then the floors will be $k-1$ and $q-1$, respectively.

Thus, either way, again using that $\alpha b - a\beta$ is prime to $n$, the the second congruence yields that $k\equiv q\pmod{n}$ in either case.

But this does not tell you that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are between the same two multiples of $n$. It only tells you that if $x_1$ is between $kn$ and $(k+1)n$, then $x_2$ will be between two multiples of $n$ that differ from $kn$ and $(k+1)n$ *by a multiple of $n$*.

For example, take $x_1 = n+1$ and $x_2=n^2+n+1$. The first congruence holds, since $x_1-x_2\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

For the second, $\frac{x_1-1}{n} = 1$ and $\frac{x_2-1}{n} = n+1$, so they equal their floors; and the difference of their floors is $n$, hence the second congruence holds as well, since $\lfloor\frac{x_1-1}{n}\rfloor - \lfloor\frac{x_2-1}{n}\rfloor = -n \equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

But in this case, $x_1\neq x_2$, contrary to the given claim.

Comment: Yes you are right. Another condition I found is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ should be less than $n^2$. I hope it will work.

Comment: @Ashish: That would imply what you want. You have that you can write $x_1$ and $x_2$ as $x_1 = pn+r$, $0\leq r\lt n$, and $x_2 = (p+kn)n  + r$, for some integers $p$ and $r$. If they must be less than $n^2$, then $k=0$ and $0\leq p\leq 1$, so $x_1=x_2$.